# Dark Region on Dell UltraSharp U3415W 34-Inch Curved LED-Lit Monitor

Tags: display, external-display

My Dell 34" monitor is having an issue where the center of the screen is dark, along with the bottom two corners. The image below is of the screen displaying a solid white color:

[image]

The strangest thing about the issue is that it occurred out of the box, then went away, and came back 9 months later (enough for Dell to void the warranty, as it was purchased originally from Amazon).

I've reset the display settings to default, and nothing changed.

I have no idea to what could possibly cause it in the first place, and am especially clueless to how it could possibly come back after working normally for 9 months. I 
haven't moved the thing, dropped it, spilled anything on it, taken it on a hiking trip, parasailing, or anything of that nature.

Is there any fix to this issue?

Comment: Have you tried a replacement video cable?

Comment: I just did, but with no luck. Good suggestion, though, I hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is simple: your backlighting, or its drive, is defective. The LED strip on the bottom has multiple sections, and one is either short or open, resulting in a blackened spot.

Since you're past warranty, I'd try opening it up and checking the connections on the LED driver.
[image]
 Maybe a connector is loosened from the shipping or at the factory was incorrectly plugged.

If there's nothing, then the lower LED strip must be replaced on your monitor. I repair this type of issue 5 days a week...so much for LEDs being durable.

Comment: It worked! It was actually the connection on the far bottom left. Thanks!

Comment: Haha, glad to hear that! Enjoy your monitor. ^_^ I've added the bottom left and right contacts to the photo, so someone else knows where to check.